# How to achieve dynamic relation with null relation allowed?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

What I am trying to achieve is a polymorphic relation of a table called 'questions'

```
Quesions
-------------
id
title
description
type
metadata_type
metadata_id
```

`Question` can be of three types, `text-type-question`, `choice-question`, `opinion-scale`.
text-type-question doesn't have any relation table it only requires a basic title and description fields. but the other two requires Extra metadata which is in another two tables whose Model specified in `metadata_type`

What I tried to do is

```
class SurveyQuestion extends Model
{
    public function metadata()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(app($this->metadata_type));
    }
}
```

This returns me the metadata fine but my `text-type-question` doesn't have any relation table, ie `$this->metadata_type` is null. so it will throw an error.

is there any way to return a null relation by checking type condition?